# How to write custom rules for sutime in stanford temporal tagger?

Tags: stanford-nlp, temporal, sutime

Stanford temporal tagger is working fine for most cases. For example "I should be in school tomorrow by 9'o clock." is having 9'o clock as time. But SUTime is not identifying it :(

So I want to add rule based on this. Any suggestions ?

I'm using [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this rule right below the "9 o'clock" rule:

```
{ ( (?: /the/ /hour/ /of/?)? ([ $INT & { numcompvalue<=24 } ]) (/'/ /o/ /clock/)) => IsoTime($1[0].numcompvalue, 0, NIL) }
```

in:

edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt

and was able to recognize the pattern you described.

Note that the tokenizer splits "9'o clock" into ["9", "'", "o", "clock"].

In general if you add rules to that file you can add custom patterns for cases you wish to cover.  That file can be found in this jar:

stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar

Comment: I'm looking for the same pattern.